# Triangulation 3D algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl, 3d

I have thousands of polygon on 3D space which contains more than 3 vertex. I want partition each polygon into a set of triangles. I have been looking all over the internet and I can not find any algorithm on 3D that does that. I have found many algorithms working on 2D like `ear clipping` and `Delaunay triangulation`. But I can not find any algorithm for 3D.

I saw many same questions on this site which answered with "use the Delaunay triangulation algorithm". But I have seen that this algorithm is for 2D:
http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~samuelp/del_project.html

> Implement an algorithm for finding the constrained Delaunay triangulation of a given point set in two dimensions.

What 3D Triangulation algorithm can I use?
I am using OpenGL with C++.

Comment: Delaunay is for point set triangulation, you need polygon triangulation which ear clipping is designed for. You can apply ear clipping to 3D by projecting the polygon onto any plane that does not degenerate it.

Comment: Constrained Delaunay triangulation works on polygons.

Comment: Just to make sure that you're not making this way more complicated than necessary: The polygons can be concave? As long as they are convex, this would of course be a trivial problem. Also, there are ways to render arbitrary polygons directly with OpenGL, using a stencil buffer. Depending on your use case, that could be an alternative.

Comment: Reto Koradi - Yes the model can be concave. And I need to store the data in variables and not directly render it. Is it possible on your way? if so, how?

Comment: I assume that each polygon is flat with respect to the plane defined by it's face normal and one of it's points? In that case why not reduce it to 2d on that plane and just use one of the  regular triangulation methods you already know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the GLUTesselator:

http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter11.html

Also note that a 3D polygon will have many faces which can be translated onto an axis aligned 2D plane, triangulated, and then the results translated back into the plane defined by the face.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a delaunay triangulation but with tetrahedons. Basically use Bowyer Watson with circumspheres:http://blog.mmacklin.com/tag/meshing/.